# How can you filter rows using read_csv ('na_values')?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I wish to filter rows using the na_values = 'NaN' command. I have assumed the code shown below would filter only rows where name == NaN, but instead an empty dataframe appears (Without any syntax error). Perhaps I have misunderstood what na_values actually does?

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Sam/Downloads/House.csv', na_values='NAN')
Data = pd.DataFrame(data)
AA_df = Data.copy()

AA_df = AA_df.loc[AA_df['Name'] == np.nan]
```

Comment: try `AA_df = AA_df.loc[AA_df['Name'] == 'NAN']` I guess you have replaced your pandas nan types with a 'NAN' string, if you leave it blank then pandas will automatically fill that for you so you can use `np.nan` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work?

Comment: That's what I cant understand. I've tried every possible variation and still can't filter by these missing values

Comment: Can you post a few rows of your data? So we can reproduce the issue?